# Having View Slide in From Bottom in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

If I have a view setup in my storyboard, is there a way that I can have that view (of a custom width and height) slide up from the bottom of my screen when a button is pressed? I would want the screen to just overlay (so that you would still be able to press things on the screen underneath).

How would I set this up?

```
func isChecked(){

    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow

    window!.addSubview(collectionView)
    let height: CGFloat = 250
    let y = window!.frame.height - 250
    collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window!.frame.height, width: window!.frame.width, height: height)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }, completion: nil)
}

func isUnchecked(){
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, window!.frame.height, self.collectionView.frame.width, self.collectionView.frame.height)
    })
}
```

Is there a way that I can accomplish what I am doing above, except with a view that I create in my storyboard?

Comment: What have you tried? This could be done in many ways, with frames or autolayout, UIView animations, etc.

Comment: There is no default transition style that will give you this effect.

Comment: @paulvs see the code I added above- how can I link a storyboard view to replace the `collectionView` that I am using now

Comment: The best way to do that is to create a `UIView` subclass (e.g. `MyView`), create an xib with the same name (e.g. 'MyView.xib', this is done via `File > New > File > User Interface > View`). Then instantiate it programatically using `let myView = UINib(nibName: "MyView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! MyView`.

Comment: Great! It works perfectly! Thanks for the help @paulvs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Swift 5 version:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
   let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 50)
   let col = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    col.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    col.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    col.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    return col
  }()

        let switchView = UISwitch()

        func switched(s: UISwitch){
           let origin: CGFloat = s.on ? view.frame.height : 50
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
                self.collectionView.frame.origin.y = origin 
            }
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            switchView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 40, height: 20)
            switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switched), forControlEvents: .valueChanged)

            view.addSubview(switchView)
            view.addSubview(collectionView)

        }

    }
```

---

I've made a little demo for you: created new project and wrote that code in **ViewController.swift**, nothing more. Think it helps

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height - 50)
        let col = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        col.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        col.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        col.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        return col
    }()

    let switchView = UISwitch()

    func switched(s: UISwitch){
        let origin: CGFloat = s.on ? view.frame.height : 50
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35) { 
            self.collectionView.frame.origin.y = origin
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        switchView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 40, height: 20)
        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switched), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

        view.addSubview(switchView)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**SwiftStudier's answer updated for Swift 3:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 50)
        let col = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        col.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        col.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        col.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        return col
    }()

    let switchView = UISwitch()

    func switched(s: UISwitch){
        let origin: CGFloat = s.isOn ? view.frame.height : 50
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.35) {
            self.collectionView.frame.origin.y = origin
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        switchView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 40, height: 20)
        switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switched), for: .valueChanged)

        view.addSubview(switchView)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
}
```