# How to hide a UIView(Collection view) while scrolling the UITableview?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to slide up the upper view(Collection view), as the user scrolls up the tableview,and reveal it as the user scrolls down.
I do not know how to go about this. I have tried looking as the scrollView didScroll function, but I am lost as how to set this up. Any advice?

[image]

Comment: You can put this collection view to a custom UITableViewCell. Note that you need to be aware of reuse identifier of this cell it should be unique for this table view.

Comment: @liya , any example please

Comment: Something like that https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Comment: Try to describe your goal with a bit more detail... What is the "See more"? Do you want that to "slide up and off the screen"? Or is that supposed to slide up, pushing the collection view, but then staying at the top of the scrolling table? And should the collection view only come back into view when the user has scrolled all the way back to the top of the table? Or do you want to "pull it down" as soon as the user starts scrolling down?

Comment: @DonMag, please check the url:-  https://imgur.com/uKzonLv

Comment: @AsIfPrince - couple options... 1) put the collection view in the `.tableHeaderView`, or 2) put the collection view in a custom cell. Note: if you expect to have additional horizontal-scrolling collection views, you'll want to do option 2.

Comment: @DonMag , as a beginner this wont  be easy for me,  anyway thank you for suggesting the solution. I will try to implement  option 2, if you have any idea or suggestions please feel free to  share with me.

Comment: @AsIfPrince - *"as a beginner this wont be easy for me"* ... well, it looks like you're trying a big task for a "beginner." The only way to learn is to, well, learn. Search for `UICollectionView in UITableViewCell` -- you'll find lots and lots of examples, tutorials, discussions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableViewDelegate` also serves `UIScrollViewDelegate` as you can see in the documentation:

```
public protocol UITableViewDelegate : UIScrollViewDelegate
```

Try this:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview).y > 0)
        {
            print("scrolled up")
            //show the collection view here
        }
        else
        {
            print("scrolled down")
            //hide the collection view here
        }
    }
```

In case you want to slide the collectionView instead of hiding it as you said in the comment below, I suggest you to follow this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38597530/13839521

Comment: By show the collection view did you mean isHeddien? or how?

Comment: Yes, try that, why not :)

Comment: by using IsHidden it's hiding the collectionview but i want the collectionview to slide up with the table view

Comment: You said : "I am trying to hide the upper view(Collection view)"
However, check my edited answer. I have provided a reference that may help you.

Comment: beg a pardon, i want to slide up the collectionview

Comment: did you make it?